# How to download audio files one by one and show progress

Tags: android, download, uiswitch

I am developing such application in which there is a switch , once the user turn on the switch all the audio files in the list should be download one by one and progress will be shown besides the name of audio file, i am facing the problem to show the particular progress, and once the user turn off the switch the download should be stop, Please help...[as shown in picture the progress will be shown besides particular downloading file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYyux.png)

Comment: make service for that.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?answertab=votes#tab-top and make your custom logic

Comment: there are few libraries available for simultaneous downloading and progress update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a beautiful [library](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader). it has a lot more features like serial/parallel downloading. but you have to create custom logic and animation according to your screen

[image]
[image]